# React: "Maximum update depth exceeded" when mapping a basic array of data into multiple components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, recursion, rendering

I am having this error `index.js:1 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.` that is running non stop has if there is an infinite React rerendering recursion going on. Yet as my page is fairly simple, and as I don't use either useEffect nor useState, I don't grasp what's triggering this error. Anyone to explain this behavior?

```
export function HomeScreen({ navigation }: any) {
  const dailyTasksElements = dailyTasksFakeData.map((task, index) => {
    return (
      <Pressable
        key={index}
        style={styles.dailyTask}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate(task.route)}
      >
        <Text>{task.description}</Text>
      </Pressable>
    )
  })
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <ProfileInformation />
          <Progression />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.dailyTasks}>{dailyTasksElements}</View>
      </View>
      <NavBar />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Try this <View style={styles.dailyTasks}>{dailyTasksElements()}</View>

Answer (score 1):

You're rendering a UI Element and putting its memory address into a const (`dailyTasksElements`).

Now this `dailyTasksElements` could be rendered and reInitialized several times without any need to do that (it's violating the rule of React reconcilliation which means reRender only if needed).

To workaround, just don't put the value of some const as a rendered component (or set of components), just declare a function and return something or make another component like below.

```
export function HomeScreen({ navigation }: any) {
  const dailyTasksElements = () => (
    <>
      {dailyTasksFakeData.map((task, index) => {
        return (
          <Pressable
            key={index}
            style={styles.dailyTask}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate(task.route)}>
            <Text>{task.description}</Text>
          </Pressable>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <ProfileInformation />
          <Progression />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.dailyTasks}>{dailyTasksElements()}</View>
      </View>
      <NavBar />
    </>
  );
}
```

or Even better

```
const DailyTasksFakeData: React.FC<{ navigation: someType }> = ({
  navigation
}) => (
  <>
    {dailyTasksFakeData.map((task, index) => {
      return (
        <Pressable
          key={index}
          style={styles.dailyTask}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate(task.route)}>
          <Text>{task.description}</Text>
        </Pressable>
      );
    })}
  </>
);

export function HomeScreen({ navigation }: any) {
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <ProfileInformation />
          <Progression />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.dailyTasks}>
          <DailyTasksFakeData navigation={navigation} />
        </View>
      </View>
      <NavBar />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's working. Thank you very much for this answer.

Nevertheless, can I ask more explainations on : "Now this dailyTasksElements could be rendered and reInitialized several times without any need to do that" ?

I don't understand why a simple map trigger the rerendering. As far as I understand, the map should be run once. Therefore this behavior is really a surprise.

Comment: Actually, this issue is not solved by your solution. After a while, the component is rerendered in a infinite loop.

Comment: @AMehmeto The reason is not the map function, the reason for `const = return map... ` isn't a good solution is that whenever some value changes, the const re-initializes, the mapping happens again while only the updated elements should be rendered, not the whole. const being used directly in the body of functional component makes everything again, like the beginning moment while (for example) only 1 element needs to be rendered again.

Answer (score 0):

It happened that my `map` was perfectly fine.

I commented my subcomponent one by one to isolate the issue and it came out that the NativeBase's `Avatar` component trigger the issue. It was located inside `ProfileInformation`.

No more error. I am very surprise but that's how I solved it. I am using my own component as much as possible now.